# Convert user input (string) into binary array to transmit over LED?

Tags: arduino

I have a project about Visible Light Communication. I need to get user input (e.g sentence) and convert this sentence into binary values so that I can turn on-off the LED.

So far I managed to transmit data but i am having issue with how to convert this string into binary.

One of the ideas that i came up with is to convert this string into 1D array with 1s and 0s. Each 8 binary element in the array represents the ascii equvialant. However i couldnt manage to achieve this task.

if you guys give me another method to complete this, it'll be greatly appriciated.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but i couldnt find it so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is only A-Z and a-z i.e. Without any special characters like spaces, periods, commas, $&()@,  etc. then you can encode them with your own encoding e.g. A=0 B=1 .... a= 26 ... z = 51. Doing this, you will need 6 bits to represent each character.

On the other hand, you could use more advanced algorithms like [Huffman coding](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to encode each character.

However, if you're having problems with transmitting the ASCII representation, you'll have a problem with those two options. I'd say stick with the ASCII encoding till you have a stronger reason to try something else.